# LINQ 2 Objects Having clause

Tags: linq-to-objects

Given a collection of MyType { int Index, string Name } what would be the technically efficient way of getting Min/Max index items?

we use:

```
MyType minIndexItem = items.Single(t=>
   t.Index == items.Min(t=>
      t.Index));
```

which doesn't look exactly elegant. We'd like to stick to lambda syntax too and we are looking for the most technically efficient approach, not sugar'ish things like extension methods etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be

```
  (from item in items select item order by item.Index).First()
```

Pretty fast if the Index field has a db index.

Comment: I thought about Linq-to-Oject in general. The query above is fast when the items represent a db table or any indexed collection.

Comment: Then it won't be called LINQ-to-Objects (which does not use indexed collections).  For example, if the collection is a set of DataRow's stored in a DataSet, then it will be called LINQ-to-DataSet...  The raw-metal LINQ-to-Objects implementation does not rely on the fact that a collection has an index or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting it will be the simple way to do it for LINQ-to-RDBMS, but probably not for LINQ-to-Objects, because the sorting may be expensive and runs in O(nlogn).

You can use LINQ aggregation to get the lowest or highest.  This runs through the entire collection exactly once, an is always O(n).  For example, to get the lowest item:

```
items.Aggregate((current, next) => next.Index < current.Index ? next : current);
```